# Overwrite view()->share key in controller method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Let say we have something like this in a `AppServiceProvider`

```
$page = [ 
   'title' => 'Page Name',
   'info'  => 'Content Here'
];

view()->share('page', $page);
```

In view:

```
<h1>{{$page['title']}}</h1>
<p>{{$page['info']}}</p>
```

If I want to overwrite `$page['title']` in method controller, I have tried like this:

```
public function index()
 {
    $page['title'] = "overwrite title only";
    return view('index', compact('page'));
 }
```

Problem is `$page['info']` will not longer be available, it will not exist in view. How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: What is `pageHeading`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Oops, I have fixed it. It should be `page`

Comment: It's because you send a new variable that containe only `title`  !!

Comment: @Maraboc Yes I am aware of that. That is why I am asking for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution could be to replace in your Controller:

```
$page['title'] = "overwrite title only";
```

with:

```
$page = array_merge(
    view()->shared('page'), 
    ['title' => "overwrite title only"]
);
```

[`view()->shared()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/View/Factory.html#method_shared) method returns the shared variable, then we can override some array elements and pass the overridden array to the view.